# Flagging a document that is not linked to in a list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, document

I have a **list** and a **library**.

The **library** contains *documents A*, *B*, and *C*.

The **list** has a lookup column pointing to the library. The list contains two items: *item 1* links to *document A* and *item 2* links to *document B*.

*Document C* is **not linked to** by a list item.

Is there a way I can **automatically flag *document C* as being an "orphan" document**?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **Yes/No** column called "Orphaned" to show if it is an orphan document, set the default value to **No**.

Then create a SharePoint Designer workflow and use IF condition to check the lookup column's value. If it is empty, set the column "Orphaned" to **Yes**.
[image]
For Start Options:
[image]